# Average home range across animals

Tags: r

Been struggling with this for a few days now. I use here a subset of my data, 3 individuals, 7 relocations each, tracked across 3 seasons. Not all fish are present in all seasons, and their locations differ between seasons. I need to estimate average home range area across fish for each season and plot it.

I think that Anthony Fischbach's reply from the thread below is what I need to do, I just stuck partway there (mainly because I'm very new to spatial analysis and adehabitatHR).

http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/averaging-home-range-contours-td7499301.html#a7503972

```
df <- structure(list(Season = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Spring", "Summer", "Fall"), class = "factor"), 
Easting = c(425952.746437786, 425930.124103401, 425904.838430173, 
425897.396103185, 425859.77203381, 425769.155466566, 425698.934422453, 
425172.162553713, 425201.54784946, 425265.188960297, 425293.907156855, 
425334.519543017, 425351.98115297, 425341.657291998, 426499.521534761, 
426491.617459401, 426489.21804795, 426458.425998741, 426444.572705444, 
426435.13014907, 426428.521796826, 425206.363932968, 425214.055516556, 
425214.686198032, 425219.462846981, 425224.610973811, 425225.509004604, 
425231.130704745, 425295.438309455, 425295.033258023, 425298.385156621, 
425286.605300153, 425292.736058183, 425296.563442322, 425289.068691518, 
425262.047903812, 425245.264536305, 425236.068286685, 425246.961026478, 
425244.291558159, 425234.858476333, 425220.329721481), Northing = c(5630038.14127036, 
5630042.68938361, 5630053.17010795, 5630050.05067675, 5630050.03021924, 
5630044.42581987, 5630080.68394433, 5631660.65042482, 5631622.41326505, 
5631580.90371775, 5631564.80939618, 5631533.30748204, 5631498.46768363, 
5631476.0382073, 5629521.34564057, 5629530.46592294, 5629545.1806574, 
5629555.1802463, 5629557.15541335, 5629572.08088964, 5629598.08820948, 
5630913.54144105, 5630904.64457731, 5630904.41307655, 5630898.56103167, 
5630889.14462961, 5630887.90831366, 5630886.93779994, 5630645.78035996, 
5630647.00958702, 5630649.85318956, 5630643.90518234, 5630648.93328633, 
5630650.5466496, 5630648.65226268, 5631661.36063509, 5631635.46509059, 
5631632.70549606, 5631635.88559859, 5631631.47516021, 5631626.93945528, 
5631610.91014489), ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("01", "04", "06"), class = "factor")), .Names =         
c("Season", 
"Easting", "Northing", "ID"), row.names = c(NA, 42L), class = "data.frame")

## following the advice in the link above:
library(adehabitatHR)
tagList <- unique(df$ID)

kud1 <- list()
kud_spdf <- list()
vd <- list()

## running a loop across animals, estimating 95% 
for(i in tagList){
thing <- SpatialPoints(subset(df[df$ID == i,], select = c(Easting, Northing)),   
proj4string = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=11 +ellps=WGS84"))
thing <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = thing, data = subset(df[df$ID == i,], select = c(Season)))
thing$Season <- as.character(thing$Season)
kud1[[i]] <- kernelUD(thing, grid = 120, extent = 0.2, same4all=TRUE)
kud_spdf[[i]] <- estUDm2spixdf(kud1[[i]]) 
    fullgrid(kud_spdf[[i]]) <- TRUE
vd[[i]] <- kud_spdf[[i]]@data 
     }
```

And then I'm stuck, since every fish in vd has a different number of points (because, as I understand, the grid is calculated separately for each fish). How do I proceed to averaging across fish, summing and normalizing the data by pixel, etc?

I'm OK with the plotting part, as long as I can use `getverticeshr` on the kernelUD objects, then run `fortify`, and plot by group using ggmap and ggplot.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your problem but why can't you work will species and seasons all together?

```
sp_df <- subset(df, select = c(IDS, Easting, Northing))
coordinates(sp_df) <- ~Easting+Northing
#plot(sp_df, axes = T, col = )
kud <- kernelUD(sp_df[ ,1], grid = 200, same4all=TRUE)
hr <- kernel.area(kud, percent = 95)

    X01Fall X01Summer X04Spring X04Summer X06Spring X06Summer
95 8.638694  8.118291  1.353048    2581.2    2581.2 0.4163226
```

and work from here to summarise the data by individuals

many options here...

```
hr1 <- as.data.frame(t(hr))
hr1$ID <- factor(rep(c(1,4,6), each = 2))
names(hr1)[1] <- 'p95'
# Using base functions
aggregate(p95~ ., hr1, mean)

# Fast and simple
library(dplyr)
hr1 %>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  summarise(mean_hr = mean(p95))
    Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

  ID   mean_hr
1  1 8.4037848
2  4 0.8040197
3  6 0.2109327
```

**EDIT**

I don´t understand the relevance of getting the mean home range when individuals display significant spatial displacement, as in this case.

```
kareas <- getverticeshr(kud, 95)
library(ggplot2)
kdareas <- fortify(kareas)
ggplot(kdareas) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group, fill = id, colour = id),
               alpha = .4) +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_equal()
```

[image: kernel area]

I don't see why you should, but that's me...

Comment: Huh. I was so intent on separating the individuals and seasons, I didn't realize I could do that... That still leaves me with the need to average across fish and such. I progressed a bit (following that link I referenced) with your help: 

kud_spdf <- estUDm2spixdf(kud) 
fullgrid(kud_spdf) <- TRUE
vd <- kud_spdf@data 
vd_all <- apply(vd, 1, sum)

## Normalize
vd_all <- data.frame(All = vd_all/sum(vd_all))

kudspdf_all <- kud_spdf
kudspdf_all@data <- vd_all 

And then got stuck again trying to "cast back into an estUD object"...

Comment: @user2602640 I'll give it a try in a moment.

Comment: Not sure that I'm getting it (or maybe I didn't specify my question well enough) - my main struggle is with calculating the **location** of the home range, not its area, so that I can plot the across-fish-range on a map. If I understand correctly, your edit estimates areas? Also - is `hr` in your edit the same as `kud` in your original reply? Baby steps here....

Comment: @user2602640. I see. It is different indeed. I'll have to think about.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and the help! The data here are just a small subset of a ~ 100K, 30-fish dataset. There are, of course, differences among individual home ranges, but in writing a paper, I can't plot 30 maps. I need to show a single (per-season) plot that shows average are use. I can do it by removing tag data and treating all data as if they came from the same fish, but that doesn't seem right, since a single fish that "really likes" one area will bias the entire range estimate. The other way to do it is by calculating individual ranges and averaging over. If I can figure out how :-)